# Jquery UI autocomplete input - How to check if input is empty on change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, autocomplete

I have a Jquery UI auto complete field on my page, and I need to do something when input becomes empty (i.e The user typed something in, then deleted all of it).

This event must fire regardless of whether what they typed in initially produced autocomplete results.

The point is to show a button if there are no autocomplete results for typed entry, and remove it if there are results OR the input is empty.

UPDATE
I have tried this...

```
$('#employeeAutocomplete').change(function() {
     alert("eventFired");
     if($( "#employeeAutocomplete" ).val() == ''){
         $('#createEmployeeBtn').hide();
     }
});
```

And alert is not displayed....

Thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-and-change-event

About the same problem:

> I've found the change: does work, but only when the input loses focus.
>
> The solution I implemented, to get the effect I desired was to implement my own check as part of the source: function. I set minLength: to 0, and if the length was less than 2 I loaded my default display data.

Answer (score 3):

Super old question, but I think I found a solution that worked great for me and may help others. So what made it work for me without dancing around `autocomplete` and what does not seem to have the flaws that `change` and `keypress` had, was `keyup`.

Simply adding `keyup` event handler next to `autocomplete` block makes the event fire regardless loosing a focus or changing the field value, even with clearing the value. This makes the feature work in all the cases I could think of. Here's the code:

```
$('#employeeAutocomplete').keyup(function() {
  if($('#employeeAutocomplete').val() === '') {
     $('#createEmployeeBtn').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this plugin

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

it's a closer handler for real textchange event

Comment: Bang on the money. This took me about 5 minutes to implement and works like a charm. None of the other solutions work. Thanks for posting this answer...

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is really old but i was trying the same think and the answers here didn't pleased me.

So for myself, i did the test of empty value on blur event of jquery.

`$('.input').focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete({
        // autocomplete code here
        })
    }).blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "") {
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you :) [.change() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: probably easier than my answer!

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to fire...not sure why...

$('#employeeAutocomplete').change(function() {
if($( "#employeeAutocomplete" ).val() == ''){
$('#createEmployeeBtn').hide();
}
});
});

Comment: Because the change() event is not fired until the input loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

try keypress

[.keypress() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: Hmmm it seems that both .keypress and .change will not play nice with the jquery autocomplete control...

Comment: do you have jquery library included in the header? try other functions, use firebug to see what the problem is

Comment: by autocomplete do you mean the field shows the results as you type?

Comment: Yeah Jquery is definitely there, been using it alot. And yeah thats what i mean by autocomplete.

Comment: I am sure you would find a solution from google within 5 minutes, just requires research skills.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#employeeAutocomplete').change(function() {
     alert("eventFired");
     if(this.value == ''){
         $('#createEmployeeBtn').hide();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery ui's autocomplete has his own change event, have you tried it?

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-change

Comment: Yeah had a look at it, seems it is triggered when field is blurred as apposed to when contents are changed.

Comment: I've used the plugin above, I posted it as an additional answer for new readers to find it faster

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue with autocomplete close event ! 
Close fired when result list is empty. Im my case this correspond with an empty input field.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-close

Answer (score 0):

OK people. The following definitely works and is an amazingly simple & elegant solution, requiring a couple of lines of code.

100% guaranteed to work.

@Milox has already mentioned it:

http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

This jQuery plugin is tiny. Once you download/copy it & link to the 'js' file, use the following:

```
jQuery('#input').bind('notext',function () {
    console.log('text field is empty');
});
```

There are other configuarations, but this was all I needed. Boom. Sorted.